# Select items in one object where a property is in a list<string>

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

ASP.NET, C#

I was doing something like this. Just need to complete it somehow.

```
var c = (from c in courseObject where 
    c.Status.Contains(selectedListItems) select c);
```

**Giving these conditions**:

courseObject = c and has properties such as c.Name, c.**Status**, c.Description

selectedListItems is List that contains "Active,Inactive,Disabled" for example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're really close. You need to do this:

```
    var c = (from c in courseObject where
    selectedListItems.Contains(c.Status) select c);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to accomplish what I assume you're trying to do.

You can revert the `.Contains()` and make it look like this:

```
var c = (from c in courseObject where
selectedListItems.Contains(c.Status) select c);
```

or you could use an `enum` instead the list that will contain your statuses.

Then your query could look something like this:

```
var c = (from c in courseObject where 
         c.Status == (int)yourEnum.Active || c.Status == (int)yourEnum.Inactive || c.Status == (int)yourEnum.Disabled
         select c);
```

Comment: Good example, I can probably use this elsewhere. Thanks!